# Counting Events Per Polygon Feature

Tags: arcgis-9.3, events

I would like to calculate the total number of events within each feature of a polygon using a dbf file and a polygon shapefile.

Is there an easy way to automate this so I can then produce charts per feature area?

Comment: What software are you using?  How are the events geolocated (e.g., as coodinates, route miles, addresses, grid codes, something else)?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.  Currently the events are in a dbf format and are simply added in via add XY Tool.  They include XY coordinates.  I know I can pull them in and convert them to a shapefile in model builder, but not quite sure how to compare them to a polygon and count the total number.  I can do a work around with the intersection and export stats for a field, manually.  However I would like to automate the process.  We should have ArcGIS 10 within the next month or so.

Answer (score 6):

Have you investigated [Spatial Joins](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Spatial_Join_%28Analysis%29)?

Comment: Yeah I was just playing around with the spatial join and the summarize function in the attribute table.  I think I can automate the process using these tools, but there has to be a better way.  Maybe with the new 10 version...

Answer (score 1):

If you make the shapefile from your xy data you can use Hawths Tools - Count Points in Polygon: [Link to Count Points in Polygons tool description](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/pntpolycnt.php)

You can download Hawths Tools for ArcGIS 9.x for free here: [Download Hawths Tools](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/download.php)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you had any issues using it with ArcGIS 9.3? Their website states that there are issues with the software when using the 9.3 version.  The tool sounds really good though.  What software are you using with it, 9.2 or 9.3?

Comment: I have been using the tool with ArcGIS 9.3 and have not encountered any problems, what so ever. I have only used a few of the available tools though, so I'm not saying, that there could not be problems with some of the tools I haven't used.

Comment: Okay, but the count tool appears to work for you.  You are using the Hawths Tools and not the newer beta software, correct?

Comment: Yes - that is correct - and I have used the count tool.